# 'kitchen test' command fails with "Could not load the 'inspec' verifier from the load path."

Tags: chef-infra

I made a new cookbook and tried testing by kitchen.

```
$ chef generate cookbook mycookbook
$ cd mycookbook
$ kitchen test
```

Result is:

```
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.11.1)
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ClientError
>>>>>> Message: Could not load the 'inspec' verifier from the load path. Please ensure that your transport is installed as a gem or included in your Gemfile if using Bundler.
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

I checked `.kitchen/logs/kitchen.log`, but there is nothing.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this error by installing the Inspec driver for Kitchen.
https://github.com/inspec/kitchen-inspec

```
# Install
gem install kitchen-inspec

# Verify error
kitchen list
```

EDIT:
I experience the same error again, this time I needed to:

- update [chefDK (4.0.60)](https://downloads.chef.io/chefdk)
- install: `chef gem install kitchen-inspec` [kitchen-inspec/issues/105](from: https://github.com/inspec/kitchen-inspec/issues/105)
  Here I was promted to accept the chef license of the new chefDK.
- verify error: `kitchen list`

Answer (score 1):

It can occur because kitchen is not initiated.

```
$ kitchen init
```